# MYSQL Change Table Engine in Batch

Tags: mysql

I need to change the whole table in a database engine from `Innodb` to `MyISAM`using MYSQL. How I can do that? Anyone ever do this before? Any helps or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you mean you want to change all tables engine of a db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT  CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` ENGINE=MyISAM;') 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdatabase'
AND     `ENGINE` = 'Innodb'
AND     `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY table_name DESC;
```

The query will give you the ALTER query which you need to execute to change the engines.

Add the ALTER query inside the stored procedure like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myProc;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
BEGIN
//Here you can put the ALTER statements.
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I got list of queries..how to execute all the list only one run time only

Comment: @Imran:- There are many ways, one is  you can copy the queries and create a stored procedure and then execute the stored procedure to get them executed at once.

Comment: Can you show me how to create with stored procedure...your help would be useful for everyone...

Comment: I try to run one query...it gives this error: `SQL Error 1217: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: A stored procedure is not necessary at all.

Comment: @Imran Create procedure command is well documented on mysql's website. How about checking it there and trying to do it yourself? Moreover, most mysql managers are perfectly capable of running the output of this answer in a batch.

Comment: @Imran:- Try to disable the constraint like `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` and then execute your query. Also make sure to enable the constraint after the ALTER statement using `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`